# Select2 not populating values after removing selected attribute by jquery

Tags: jquery-select2

I've implemented select2 for multiselect 
My select2 element is as bellow:

```
<input type="text" name="reply_to[]" class="form-control populate placeholder" multiple="multiple" id="recipient_name_rply" required="" >
```

on change of another dropdown I'm removing previously selected users using this jQuery code:

```
$('#recipient_name_rply').data().select2.updateSelection(null);
```

It's working fine for removing selected options. But problem is when it removed selected options select2 is unable to display newly searched results in select2 dropdown. please solve the problem. thanks

Comment: thanks for correcting question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't make it null it will remove html that select2 use to populate data. replace your code

```
$('#recipient_name_rply').data().select2.updateSelection(null);
```

with

```
$('#recipient_name_rply').data().select2.updateSelection([]);
```

I hope it will work.